# What's the difference between "Blood group" and "Blood type"?

Tags: synonyms

Do *blood group* and *blood type* refer to different classifications of blood (A, B, AB, O vs. something else), or are they used in different contexts to refer to the same thing?

Comment: Never heard of *blood group*. *Blood type* is A, B, AB, O, and a few crazy cases at least in American English.

Comment: @virmaior Some have never heard of *blood type*, they always knew it as *blood group*!

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blood+group **blood group** *n* **1**. (Medicine) any one of the various groups into which human blood is classified on the basis of its agglutinogens. Also called: **blood type**

Comment: @kris. Point noted ... and this would be British English? or ...

Comment: @virmaior Currently, the terms are synonyms and completely interchangeable in both AmE & BrE. However, *blood type* appears about four times more frequently on COCA (AmE), than *blood group*.

Comment: @Kris - they are not completely interchangeable in AmE, nor, I suspect, BrE.

Comment: @Kris ... so this is just a case of AmE vs. BrE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blood group and blood type are largely synonymous, but are often not used synonymously.

[this article](http://www.nobelprize.org/educational/medicine/landsteiner/readmore.html) discusses blood groups, and introduces the act of blood typing as well.

*Blood group* tends to be used when discussing the A, B, AB, O, and Rh blood cell surface antigens.

> The discovery of the ABO blood [group](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK2267/), over 100 years ago, caused great excitement.

*Blood type* tends to be used when discussing individual members of a blood group, e.g.

> 8-yr-old Thalassaemia patient with rare blood [type](http://www.thenews.com.pk/article-133975-8-yr-old-Thalassaemia-patient-with-rare-blood-type-looking-for-donors) looking for donors

In addition to the ABO and Rh types are many more types which aren't contained in groups, such as H (or Bobmay antigen)  and Le -/+ (Lewis) types. In the article about the child with a rare blood type, his type is found in only 14 people in Pakistan.

Answer (score 0):

They mean the exact same thing. I would guess that they are used in different contexts but could be used in the same context.

Answer (score 0):

In my own understanding Blood Group is being used or consider in legal point of view or when identifying blood in some court appearances while blood type is usually used in medical point of view..as to determine the blood group of the individual.

Comment: Hello, orland-badiango, welcome to EL&U! The answer box is rather strictly reserved for [answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) with arguments and linked references. You could improve this answer by stating where your understanding of this usage comes from. Cheers!